# how to upgrade schema to create new table in existing module in magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, database, table

I need to create a table having  id,customer_id,in_time,out_time,in_coordinates,out_coordinates where customer_id will be primary key.
please tell what are the steps after creating sql file in sql folder.?

my file name is :
mysql4-data-upgrade-0.1.15-0.1.16.php

```
$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();

$installer->run("
-- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {$this->getTable('sm_tracker')};
CREATE TABLE {$this->getTable('sm_tracker')} (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Inc Id',
  `customer_id` varchar(30) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Customer Id',
  `punch_in_time` varchar(30) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Punch-In Time ',
  `punch_out_time` varchar(30) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Punch-Out Time',
  `in_coordinates` varchar(30) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Punch-In Coordinates',
  `out_coordinates` varchar(30) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Punch-Out Coordinates',

  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;");

$installer->endSetup(); 

?>
```

config.xml --> version

```
 <modules>
    <Test_Manager>
      <version>0.1.16</version>
    </Test_Manager>
  </modules>
```

and defined : in config

```
.....
     <smtracker>
                    <table>sm_tracker</table>
                  </smtracker>
            </entities>
```

Answer (score 6):

It's pretty simple. You will need to edit `config.xml` and add few files.
First, edit your config.xml file:

In `<entities>` section add this:

```
             <entities>
                <unique_name>
                    <table>your_table_name</table>
                </unique_name>
            </entities>
```

Now, check the **version** and note of the version number. For example if version is `<version>1.0.2</version>` then note of `1.0.2`.

Then go to your sql setup folder and create a file called `upgrade-1.0.2-1.0.3.php`. Add all sql codes in this file:

```
<?php

$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();

//id,customer_id,in_time,out_time,in_coordinates,out_coordinates where customer_id

$table = $installer->getConnection()
    ->newTable($installer->getTable('module_name/unique_name')) //this will select your table
    ->addColumn('id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
        'identity'  => true,
        'nullable'  => false,
        'primary'   => true,
        ), 'Id')
    ->addColumn('customer_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
        'nullable'  => false,
        ), 'Customer Id')
    ->addColumn('in_time', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP, null, array(
        ), 'In Time') //you may want to check TYPE
    ->addColumn('out_time', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP, null, array(
        ), 'Out Time') //you may want to check TYPE
    ->addColumn('out_coordinates', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT, 20, array(
        ), 'Out coordinates') //check type

    ->addColumn('user_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
        'unsigned'  => true,
        ), 'User Id')
    ->addIndex($installer->getIdxName('module_name/unique_name', array('customer_id')),
        array('customer_id'))
    ->addForeignKey($installer->getFkName('module_name/unique_name', 'customer_id', 'customer/entity', 'entity_id'),
        'customer_id', $installer->getTable('customer/entity'), 'entity_id',
        Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE, Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE)
    ->setComment('Your comment');

$installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);

$installer->endSetup();
```

You also would want to add `Model/Uniquename.php` and Resource class for your new table.

Now, check the `<version>` in `config.xml` and increase by one. For ex. if current version is like this: `<version>1.0.2</version>` then make it `<version>1.0.3</version>`

And finally, clear your cache. This should install the table for you.

**Backup your site before updating any module. This is the best practise.**

Comment: perfect answer!!! +1 :)

Answer (score 3):

create **upgrade** file. The name of file will be **upgrade-yourpreviousversion-updatedversion.php** like **upgrade-0.1.0-0.1.1.php**

```
 <?php
$installer = $this;  
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->run("
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `test`;
  CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `in_time` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `out_time` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `in_coordinates` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `out_coordinates ` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `customer_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`customer_id`)         
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;");
$installer->endSetup();
```

Comment: my file name is :
mysql4-data-upgrade-0.1.15-0.1.16.php

Comment: 0.1.16 must be you current version `<version>0.1.16</version>` and name will be `mysql4-upgrade-0.1.15-0.1.16.php`

Comment: see my updated file

Comment: @supriyamishra you are good to go just disabled the cache

Comment: should i delete file and create new with new upgrade version its not reflecting

Comment: check `core_resource` table for current module version